# Laravel user active attribute

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have no clue if it even is possible but, If I add an "is_active" column to my user table. Can I make it work like the following?
If the user is online, this turns to true so that I can make something in HTML like "Person active". And the same goes for if the individual goes offline.  I somehow need to track if a person is online or offline and that for all registered users. How can I do this?

Tips are welcome!
Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: I think it's possible and you have to change the value of `is_active` to tue in the logging function and to false in the logout one !

Comment: if logout triggers `is_active` to be false than it's probably a bad idea. Maybe you can have a continuously running loop in js that, say, every minute, calls server and sets value of `is_active` to 1, and also have some kind of cron job that every minute sets value of `is_active` to 0. Also you need 3rd continuously running loop that will check db for value of `is_active` and update ui accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You should use some Javascript or any other software that can communicate for example to the Laravel API. But at first you should declare when is a user online or offline.